# How to make the ObjectId of an array object as reference to other array in same Mongo Collection using mongoose in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a use-case in which I need to store the Object Id of an array object in other array object as the reference of same collection. Please consider the following collection.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var schema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    company     : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'company', required: false},

    timeline  : [{
                  status_id  : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user_dropdowns', refquired: false},
                  message    : {type: String, required: false},
                  time       : {type: Date, default: Date.now(), required: false},
                  messagedBy : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'company_contacts', required: false}
                }],
    comments  : [{
                  timeLineId:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'tickets.timeline', required: false},
                  comment: {type: String, required: false},
                  commentedBy : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'company_contacts', required: false},
                  commentedTime : {type: Date, required: false, default: Date.now()}
                }]
  },
  {
    versionKey: false,
    timestamps: true
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("tickets", schema, "tickets");
```

In my collection, in `comments`, I need to store the reference of `timeline` as per my requirements. Is it possible? or are there any alternatives? Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi there! The value of `timeLineId ` you want to store in `comments` should reference the whole `timeline` array right?

Comment: Yes, I want to store the whole array's ObjectId. @Tunmee

Comment: Well, I don’t think the kind of referencing is achievable. This is because the `timeLineId` value is an array, it does not store an _id or any other identifier property at the top level. Moreover, the comments and timeline array are in the same data scope, why do you want to reference one in another? From the data schema, whenever you have comments you are always doing to get the timeline data, why make an extra query for data that is already available?

Comment: I want to group the comments based on time line data